# IIS asks for login/pass when accessed using hostname but not when ‘localhost’ is used. Why?

Tags: iis, authentication

I have setup IIS on my xp machine and have setup a default homepage (that comes with the IIS installed). It is a help page I think.

when I access the page with http : // localhost it works fine (IE/Chrome or FF) but when I access it using http://hostname it prompts for a loging/password and works when I enter my domain id and password on the intranet.

I have ensured that "anonymous access" is enabled in the properties window of the default site and "websites" node.

I searched stack overflow for similar queries but some indicate I need to change the IE/FF settings to allow "integrated security" etc and some suggest to look at the "log file".

I don't want to change the IE setting and there is nothing unusual in the log file of the IIS Server.

Can anybody help me figure out why this is happening?

thank you sb

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `http://<hostname>` in Internet Explorer,  "Security for local intranet".

Steps:- Go to IE --> Tools --> Internet Options --> Security --> Local intranet --> Sites and add `http://<hostname>` 
where `<hostname>` is the name of the computer that is hosting IIS.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to IIS Manager
2. Go to the Properties of the website
3. Go to "Directory setting" and then Edit
4. Check "Integrated Windows Authentication"